# Characterization of fully faithful functors as objects in a functor category

Tags: category-theory

Let $F:C\to D$ be fully faithful. Is it possible for the category $D^C$ to "detect" this property? That is, given an equivalence $\theta : D^C \to B^A$, must $\theta F : A \to B$ also be fully faithful? If so, what categorical properties of $F$ as an object of $D^C$ determine this? Morally, it seems that the answer to this question should be "yes," but the relevant $n$Lab pages didn't seem to say much on this point. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Obviously not. For instance, suppose all of the categories involved are actually sets. Then fully faithful functors are the same as injective maps, so you are asking if bijections of function-sets preserve injectivity.

Comment: Does $D^C$ come with any structure beyond being merely a category so that it *is* able to somehow detect full and faithfulness?

Comment: If you remember the evaluation functor $D^C \times C \to D$ then yes, but that's somehow tautological.

Comment: This seems related to the common fallacy of assuming that the image of an object under a self-equivalence of a category should be isomorphic to the original object, which also has no reason at all to hold, except in the rare cases that the object has a universal property which can be stated without referencing any other objects.